# Why do I get different results if I run this code inside main() versus without main()?

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code.  If I just execute it (using IDLE Shell) without enclosing in main() I get different results then if I enclose it in main().

Example, if I run without main() and reply "a" to the first prompt and "b" to the second prompt, after the exec() instruction, name prints out changed from "a" to "b". But if I place the code in def main() the exec() instruction doesn't change name to "b", it remains as "a".

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter variable name:")
    action = input ('enter action  ')
    print("printing name  ",name)
    print("printing action  ",action)
    print("Now using exec")
    exec("name=action")
    print("printing name  ",name)
    print("printing action", action)
     
main()
```

I want the user to enter the name of a variable in my program and then specify a new value for that variable.

I have tried key/value pair, but might have not done it correctly. I have tried `locals()[name] = action`.

I believe I have tried all the "dynamically set local variable" threads on this site and others.  I must be missing something in those steps.  What posted above is the closest I could get.

Comment: The answer has to do with what scope `exec` affects when you don't pass explicit namespaces. However, you don't really need to worry about that, because you should almost never be using `exec` in the first place. If you need to dynamically update a key/value pair, use an explicit dictionary, not the the global(?) namespace.

Comment: As written, though, `exec` is assigning the value of `action` to the *name* `name`, not a variable whose name is stored in the variable `name`.

Comment: agree with @chepner. In my few years of Python programming experience I have never (1) use `exec()` (2) Pollute the global namespace by not using `main()` to wrap stuff

Comment: Further, you can check the identify of an object with `id()` (eg. `print(id(name))` to check whether two objects (`name` and `action`) point to the same address.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: The RIGHT way to do this is to have your customizable variables in a dictionary.  Then, updating it is easy: `vars[name] = action`.  You should not be letting users dink with your global namespace.  That's way too dangerous.  You CAN fix your statement by making it `exec(f"{name} = {action}")`, but it's a really really bad idea.

Comment: Tim, I can create a dictionary, vars, with key/value pairs.  The user can enter a name and action.  The action replaces the existing value.  But then I need every key to be converted to a variable and the variable is equal the value.  Example: vars={'Joe':'boy','Mary':'girl'}.  The user enters Joe for name and dog for the action.  vars becomes {'Joe':'dog','Mary:'girl"}  Then I need variables Joe and Mary with Joe='dog' and Mary='girl'.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe I found a solution but it is pretty messy.  I found "itemgetter" which will retrieve the value for a given key.  I think that avoids the risk associated with exec() or other methods.  But it requires me to type in all my names twice.

To expand my situation.  I have, for example N+1 variables called names and N+1 values for the variables.  In my present case, N is 12 but increasing as I add more items.

I create the dictionary:

```
vars={'name0': value0, name1:value1,......nameN:valueN}
```

Then, the user enters name and value (note in my first post I used **action** but using the term **value** aids understanding) and then:

`vars[name]=value`.

Then I move all the values into my variables:

```
name0=itemgetter('name0')(vars)
name1=itemgetter('name1')(vars)
.
.
.
nameN=itemgetter('nameN')(vars)
```

Thus I guess it works but it is messy to type the names once for the dictionary and again for setting the values to the names.  Of course when I add a new name I have to remember add it in two places.

Any ideas for improvement?